# Javascript syntax--what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. I have two documents--an old and a new--that I am comparing. However, I am getting a syntax error somewhere in the code below.
Somewhere in here, my code is blowing up. The error says "expression does not eval to a function." Any syntactic ideas of where I'm writing an incorrect statement?

```
if(userCtx.name != oldDoc.Document.attributeA) { 
        for (var key in oldDoc.Document)
        {
          if(newdoc.Document.hasOwnProperty('key')
          {
            if(oldDoc.Document[key] != newDoc.Document[key])
            {
               if(key === 'attributeB')
               {
                 return;
               }
               else
               {
                 throw(forbidden: 'Only admins may change this field.')
               }
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're missing a ")" after hasOwnProperty("key")

Comment: Also, vlad makes a good point about your "throw" statement below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To throw an object literal, replace the round brackets with curly brackets:

```
throw {
    forbidden: 'Only admins may change this field.'
};
```

Answer (score 7):

```
if(newdoc.Document.hasOwnProperty('key') <-- I am missing a )
```

Comment: Yes! wow. Thanks. Still getting the error, so I guess there's something else as well...

Answer (score 0):

Is the code you posted inside of a function definition? I've seen that error when defining functions that get passed as arguments to something else, and forgotten to wrap the function in parenthesis.
For example:
    `"compare": "function(docA, docB) { ... }"`
should be:
    `"compare": "(function(docA, docB) { ... })"`

Answer (score 0):

And possibly one more...
Is this inside a function? If not you might be getting an error on the `return;`